# User plugin not compatible with other Theme

Tags: octobercms

I was trying to build a site with OctoberCMS with user login and installed 'user' plugin per video instruction and added account component `{% component 'account' %}` in login page and session `[session] security = "all"` in the default layout.

Used the same process in 'Demo' theme and 'Material Design Lite'theme - in Demo theme this function of user creation, deactivation etc, was perfect but in 'Material Desing Lite' - it gets stuck and unable to create new user only.

Comment: Can you show us error logs please.

Comment: Hi Mittul at TechnoBrave, Sorry I am new to octoberCMS - I just tried figuring out the log in both CMS backend and Folders of installation, unable to find - can I request you to help me with that as well - thanks.

Comment: Please do find the snap shot link incase if it might help. Link [ https://drive.google.com/open?id=12qY2Wz6nuYHELYUIGVATZvHdGUkHRUaJ  ]

Comment: After inserting  {% framework extras %} got the following errors on the page.

{Uncaught Error: The jQuery library is not loaded. The OctoberCMS framework cannot be initialized.
    at framework.js:9
framework.extras.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oc' of undefined
    at framework.extras.js:9
    at framework.extras.js:256}

Comment: Found the soultion - Missing Jquery file in Theme folder - uploaded the 'assests\vendor' folder from demo to Material Desing Lite theme and called the {% framework extras %} in default.htm before {%scripts%}

Comment: @BalaKrishnanD Please provide an answer to your own question. This ensures that anyone else that has the problem can easily see the answer

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this question with your own comment so this can close:

**The jQuery file was missed in Theme folder** - uploaded the 'assests\vendor' folder from demo to Material Desing Lite theme and called the {% framework extras %} in default.htm before {%scripts%}